# Macbook spamming email with alert emails

Tags: mail.app, email, calendar

I've just bought a new MacBook Pro 14" and since I configured it with my Google account I started receiving email notifications about my calendar events. Apparently, Macbook is adding extra alerts to each event (although I have my notifications configured in Google Calendar and I am happy with it.

[image]

As you can see, it's even worse as it apparently sends an email every minute or so until I dismiss the alert on my MacBook. How do I stop the Calendar app / MacBook from sending these alerts?